# How to fetch all rows with one matching condition in Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with two tabs - Common and Dubai.
Common has several columns, namely TGID, CID, City, Country and Comment. 
I want to fetch all the records that have Country = Dubai. 
Eg.: The formula should help me fetch rows 4 & 5 (Image Attached)
Thanks! 
[Snippet of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTHcq.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FILTER` function. Based on your snippet, `FILTER(A2:E__, D2:D__="Dubai")`, where __ is the last row in your data. Also, instead of typing "Dubai" in the formula you can also reference another cell with the country name in it.

Reference: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en